# use block_load to load the same block with parameters?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have defined a "userinfo_Block" block to show special user's info. I have a userlist.tpl.php template file.

What I want to do on this page is using `block_load()` to display each user's info, but I don't know how to send the userid to the block.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Blocks don't have arguments/parameters, they work out their own context internally (for example a block provided by the views module might gather a contextual filter from the current URL, or the current user, etc.) Their intended use is to assigned to regions, which are then rendered in a template file. If you don't want to use that workflow, it would probably be better not to use blocks and just code something custom

Comment: Do you want to show info about currently logged in user? If not, how do you want to determine who's info should be shown?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've explained above, a custom module is required (I called mine MODULE) and you will have your hook_block info() which will declare the block:

```
function MODULE_block_info()
{
    $blocks = array();

    $blocks["userinfo_Block"] = array(
        "info" => t("User Info Block"),
    );

    return $blocks;
}
```

And hook_block_view() which will define the block. Below I have set the block content to the return value of the function userinfo_Block():

```
function MODULE_block_view($delta = "")
{
    $block = array();

    switch ($delta)
    {
        case "userinfo_Block":
            $block["content"] = userinfo_Block();
            break;
    }

    return $block;
}
```

Now, the function that creates the block:

```
function userinfo_Block()
{
    global $user;
//print out user, remember to check for no user
print_r($user);
}
```

Comment: Also, the function should be `userinfo_block`, not `userinfo_Block` to conform to the [Drupal Coding Standards](https://drupal.org/coding-standards) :-)

Comment: thanks！ i use the code below:print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('give_topic_user_tree_form', $comment->uid));
so I think use hook_theme  and then use theme('',array) to accept the parameters.